# Compare datagridview cell value with image in the DataGridViewImageColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview, compare, datagridviewcolumn

I have created a `DataGridViewImageColumn` and want to perform operation if the value of the image cell is green check box image.
The code is given below. But its not going inside the condition

```
if (dgvException.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["colStock"].Value 
                                              == Properties.Resources.msQuestion)
{
    //Some code
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking equality for images using the equality operator (`==`) doesn't work the way you need it to work.  That's why with your equality check always returns false.

You need to find out if the *content* of two images are the same -- to do this you'll need to do a pixel by pixel check of the image in the DGV cell and the reference image.  I found a few links to [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/image-comparison-using-C-Sharp/) that demonstrates comparing two images.  I've taken the image comparison algorithm from the article and condensed it into a method that takes two `Bitmaps` to compare as parameters and returns true if the images are identical:

```
private static bool CompareImages(Bitmap image1, Bitmap image2) {
    if (image1.Width == image2.Width && image1.Height == image2.Height) {
        for (int i = 0; i < image1.Width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < image1.Height; j++) {
                if (image1.GetPixel(i, j) != image2.GetPixel(i, j)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

(warning: code not tested)

Using this method your code becomes:

```
if (CompareImages((Bitmap)dgvException.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["colStock"].Value, Properties.Resources.msQuestion)) {
    //Some code 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Jay Riggs. The code worked like a charm. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: For a small image it's fine, but what about large images?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the cell Tag property to add a text value that represents the image - eg a number or name and use this to check what image is displayed. .

Answer (score 1):

S.Ponsford answer worked very well in my case, I did this generic example. PD: Take on mind  my column 0 is my DataGridViewImageColumn

```
if (this.dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Tag == null)
{                                                    
     this.dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value= Resource.MyResource1;
     this.dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Tag = true;                       
}
else
{
     this.dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = Resources.MyResource2;
     this.dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Tag = null;                        
}
```